# How can I find the isnull() value in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, isnull

```
In[17]: train_data.isnull()
Out[17]: 
       Category  Title
0         False  False
1         False  False
2         False  False
3         False  False
4         False  False
        ...    ...
98013     False  False
98014     False  False
98015     False  False
98016     False  False
98017     False  False

[98018 rows x 2 columns]

In [18]: print(train_data.isnull().sum())
Category    0
Title       1
dtype: int64
```

In train_data, there is one null value in csv file.
I need to find a null value and remove it.

Comment: use ``dropna`` to drop the rows, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you know the NA value is in the field Title

```
train_data.dropna(subset=['Title'])
```

2. If you want to remove all NAs

```
train_data.dropna()
```

3. View columns with NA

```
train_data.isna().any()
```

4. If you want to view the NA values

```
train_data[train_data.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use this to drop the rows that contains null values from dataset: `train_data.dropna()`

2. Use this to fill null value with any value say 0: `train_data.fillna(0)`
3. If you want to know which column contains null value then try it:
   [image]
4. Filtering out None value: `train_data[train_data["column_name"].notnull()]`

Answer (score 0):

I catch the type of NaN is float.
So I use it.

```
for i in range(len(train_data)):
    if type(train_data.Title[i]) == float:
        print(i)
```